# While parsing JSon data getting Error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I am using c# to serialize some data to `JSON` and sending it to javascript using below code :

```
string serializedDS = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ftpd);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", string.Format("Func('{0}');", serializedDS), true);
```

The output of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ftpd)` is `{"FTPUserName":"XKK\\xpuser1","FTPPassword":"xpr@fr@12","FTPServerAddress":"255.255.255.0","FTPPath":"In/Files"}`

My javascript function :

```
function Func(serializedDS) {
    var result = JSON.parse(serializedDS);
    if (result != null)
    {
        var a = result["FTPUserName"];
        var b = result["FTPPassword"];
        var c = result["FTPServerAddress"];
        var d = result["FTPPath"];

    }
}
```

The data recevied as function argument is `serializedDS = "{"FTPUserName":"XKK\xpuser1","FTPPassword":"xpr@fr@12","FTPServerAddress":"255.255.255.0","FTPPath":"In/Files"}"`

But at the line `var result = JSON.parse(serializedDS);` I am getting this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 20
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: instead of String.Format... can you try with a variable that you can track in javascript something like                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", string.Format("var x = {0}; console.log(x);", serializedDS), true);

Comment: Since the string you show us does not cause problems, and since there is no "token x in JSON at position 20" in that string, I conclude that quite likely the string you think was parsed is not the string that was actually parsed.

Comment: @Mörre : I have updated with the test data. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: seems like the \\ causing issues for you

Comment: @SrikantSahu : I think it is not the issue, since c# displays it like that. But the exact value in database in received at client side. I think the `\` is causing the issue. but not sure how to fix

Comment: Please try this in the console...    Func('{"FTPUserName":"XKK\\xpuser1","FTPPassword":"xpr@fr@12","FTPServerAddress":"255.255.255.0","FTPPath":"In/Files"}')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by 2 backslashes. I have changed the Func to deal with Json object directly.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", string.Format("var result = {0}; setData();", serializedDS), true);
```

In javascript create the below function.

```
function setData() {

if (result != null)
{
    var a = result["FTPUserName"];
    var b = result["FTPPassword"];
    var c = result["FTPServerAddress"];
    var d = result["FTPPath"];

}}
```